# Send and Receive data through same Socket in JZMQ

Tags: zeromq, jzmq, reliable-multicast

I am developing a JAVA multicast application using JZMQ (PGM protocol).

Is it possible to send and receive data through the same socket?

If **`ZMQ.PUB`** is used, only `send()` works and `recv()` is not working.

If **`ZMQ.SUB`** is used, `send()` doesn't work.

Is there any alternative way for using both `send()` and `recv()` using the same Socket?

```
ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
socket.send(msg);
socket.recv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Radio broadcast will never deliver your voice into the Main Station

Yes, both parts of the ZeroMQ **`PUB/SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern's archetypes **are uni-directional** ( by-definition ) one can just `.send()`, the other(s) may just listen ( and if were configured well, they will ).

---

### How to do what you have asked for? <sup>( ... and forget to have this using `pgm://` )</sup>

Yes, there are ways to use other ZeroMQ archetypes for this - i.e. a single socket over **`PAIR/PAIR`** endpoints( capable of both `.send()` and `.recv()` methods ) or a pair of **`(A)->--PUSH/PULL->-(B)`** + **`(A)-<-PULL/PUSH-<-(B)`** so as to construct the bi-directional signalling / messaging channel by using just uni-directional archetypes.

You also need to select an appropriate transport-class for being used in **`.bind()`** + **`.connect()`** between the configured ZeroMQ endpoints.

```
// -------------------------------------------------------- HOST-(A)
   ZMQ.Context aCONTEXT   = ZMQ.context( 1 );

   ZMQ.Socket  aPubSOCKET = aCONTEXT.socket( ZMQ.PUB );
               aPubSOCKET.setsockopt(        ZMQ.LINGER, 0 );
// ----------------------
               aPubSOCKET.bind( "tcp://*:8001" );
// ----------------------
// set msg = ...;
// ----------------------
               aPubSOCKET.send( msg, ZMQ.NOWAIT );

// ...
// ----------------------
               aPubSOCKET.close();
               aCONTEXT.term();
// ----------------------
```

The SUB-side has one more duty ...

```
// -------------------------------------------------------- HOST-(B)
   ZMQ.Context aCONTEXT   = ZMQ.context( 1 );

   ZMQ.Socket  aSubSOCKET = aCONTEXT.socket( ZMQ.SUB );
               aSubSOCKET.setsockopt(        ZMQ.LINGER,     0 );
               aSubSOCKET.setsockopt(        ZMQ.SUBSCRIBE, "" );
// ----------------------
               aSubSOCKET.connect( "tcp://<host_A_IP_address>:8001" );
// ----------------------
// def a msg;
// ----------------------
         msg = aSubSOCKET.recv( ZMQ.NOWAIT );

// ...
// ----------------------
               aSubSOCKET.close();
               aCONTEXT.term();
// ----------------------
```